# How can a web page get my phone number via the Google Now browser?

Tags: security, chrome-for-android, google-now

I tapped on one of the cards in Google Now, which took me to breitbart.com. A few seconds later, I got redirected to cinemobi.club and was told that I signed up for a paid subscription to that web site, which was immediately followed by an *SMS* saying:

> FreeMsg:You've subscribed to Cinemobi for £1.99/week.Free for first 24hrs. Unsubscribe? send STOP CINEMOBI to 80206.Need help? Call 08009247988

How is this even possible? I didn't enter my phone number and I'd never entered any personal information in this browser (or Chrome) because I only use Firefox, except when opening a link in Google Now because they don't honour my browser preference by default.

Here's the link I opened originally: http://www.breitbart.com/national-security/2017/04/13/venezuela-socialist-mob-assaults-archbishop-caracas-holy-thursday/

In case it helps, there must be some JavaScript code in that page that made a POST request to cinemobi.club, based on the screen I got when trying to go back:

[image]

I'm using a Nexus 5X with the latest patches.

Comment: If I may, let me suggest you a browser which is reasonably secure. Rather than using Firefox or Chrome, you may want to opt for **IceCatMobile**, which (like Firefox) lets you add extensions to further personalize its behavior. I'm suggesting so because my IceCatMobile, with the **uBlock** extension, blocked 32 requests to other sites, one of which could have caused your redirection to **cinemobi.club**. *I'm not affiliated with any of the abovementioned apps. I recommended IceCat over Firefox due to news of built-in advertising and too much info going back home inside the latter.*

Comment: Furthermore, I have no real answer to your question. However, as Google likes to install their apps as system apps, they are granted far more control on your system than other software, so beware.